# How do I one-hot encode an array of strings with Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I know there are sub-optimal solutions out there, but I'm trying to optimise my code. So far, the shortest way I found is this:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

target = np.array(['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat'])

oe = OrdinalEncoder()
target = oe.fit_transform(target.reshape(-1, 1)).ravel()
target = np.eye(np.unique(target).shape[0])[np.array(target, dtype=np.int32)]
print(target)
```

> [[0. 1.] 
>   [0. 1.]
>   [1. 0.]
>   [1. 0.]
>   ...

This is ugly code, and very long. Remove any part of it and it won't work. I'm looking for a simpler way, that won't involve calls to more than half a dozen functions from two different libraries.

Comment: What is the `target` produced by `oe`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it. This will work with arrays of any number of unique values.

```py
import numpy as np

target = np.array(['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 
    'cat', 'cat', 'hamster', 'hamster'])

def one_hot(array):
    unique, inverse = np.unique(array, return_inverse=True)
    onehot = np.eye(unique.shape[0])[inverse]
    return onehot

print(one_hot(target))
```

> Out[9]:  
>   [[0., 1., 0.], 
>          [0., 1., 0.], 
>          [1., 0., 0.], 
>          [1., 0., 0.], 
>          [1., 0., 0.], 
>          [0., 1., 0.], 
>          [0., 1., 0.], 
>          [1., 0., 0.], 
>          [1., 0., 0.], 
>          [0., 0., 1.], 
>          [0., 0., 1.]])

Comment: `preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` also does this, though your's is faster.

Comment: Any particular reason you didn't use the `return_inverse` argument to `numpy.unique`, instead of `numpy.searchsorted`? Also, you're calling `numpy.array` on something that's already an array in `np.array(array)`.

Comment: Also, using `return_counts=True` is unnecessary. You're only using the result for its length, but that length is the same length as `words`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder)?

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
>>> ohe = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto', sparse=False)
>>> arr = ohe.fit_transform(target[:, np.newaxis])
>>> arr
array([[0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.]])
```

It stores nice metadata about the transformation:

```
>>> ohe.categories_
[array(['cat', 'dog'], dtype='<U3')]
```

Plus you can easily convert back:

```
>>> ohe.inverse_transform(arr).ravel()
array(['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat'],
      dtype='<U3')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use keras and LabelEncoder for it

```
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# define example
data = np.array(['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat'])

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
data = label_encoder.fit_transform(data)
# one hot encode
encoded = to_categorical(data)
```

Comment: This is not NumPy