# For all elements in a Numpy array, return their index in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given an array:

`big_array = np.array(['dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog'])`

I want to get the position of each of these elements, in a smaller array:

`small_array = np.array(['dog', 'cat'])`

It should return:

`[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]`

It would be the equivalent of:

`[np.where(i == small_array)[0][0] for i in big_array]`

Can it be done without list comprehension, preferably with a Numpy function?

Comment: Are they guaranteed to exist?  If not, what value should be returned for elements not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to sort `small_array`, this will do it:

```
small_array.sort() # in-place, or `x = np.sort(small_array)` for a sorted copy
np.searchsorted(small_array, big_array)
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you are going with your first line, but your second line was sufficient to make it work.

Comment: @NicolasGervais: See the documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html - `searchsorted()` *requires* that the first argument is sorted, or you have to provide a third argument to tell it how to sort (as in Austin's answer).  If you do neither of those things, it will give you wrong results (including for your example input).

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58676588/how-do-i-one-hot-encode-an-array-of-strings-with-numpy/58676802#58676802) is what I was trying to do, and it works if I only use your second line of code.

Answer (score 2):

There's is no numpy function as far as I know, but you could also do a combination of `argsort` and `searchsorted` something like:

```
import numpy as np

big_array = np.array(['dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog'])

small_array = np.array(['dog', 'cat'])

sortd = np.argsort(small_array)
res = sortd[np.searchsorted(small_array[sortd], big_array)]

print(res)
# [0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare with broadcasting and find index of  `True` in the result along the last axis.

```
>>> a = np.array(['dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog'])
>>> b = np.array(['dog','cat'])
>>> c = a[:,None] == b
>>> c.argmax(axis=-1)
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], dtype=int64)
```

---

```
>>> a[:,None] == b
array([[ True, False],
       [False,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False],
       [False,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [ True, False]])
```